# Reverse Engineering bootloader

Tags: ida, arm

I am in trouble with GearFit bootloader. I can not find the load address when disassembled into IDA pro.....

Here is the [**link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6n56v6d5rrvkrfb/bootloader.bin?dl=0.) to download it.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at this [excellent explanation of the ARM boot process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139952/what-is-the-booting-process-for-arm) by Igor Skochinsky. Loading the boot loader at address 0, Architecture ARM, results in the first few lines

```
ROM:00000000 dword_0         DCD 0x20002DE0
ROM:00000004                 DCD 0x20016AAD
ROM:00000008                 DCD 0x2000E241
ROM:0000000C                 DCD 0x2000E245
ROM:00000010                 DCD 0x2000E2B5
ROM:00000014                 DCD 0x2000E32D
ROM:00000018                 DCD 0x2000E3A5
ROM:0000001C                 DCD 0
ROM:00000020                 DCD 0
```

So, 0x20002DE0 is the initial stack pointer, and `0x20016AAD` is the entry point.

That entry point does not seem to be contained in the boot loader itself (which has 64 K + 256 bytes), but in the on-Chip ROM. From the answer:

> Note that in the modern complex chips such as OMAP3 or Apple's A4 the
>   first piece of code which is executed is usually not user code but the
>   on-chip Boot ROM. It might check various conditions to determine where
>   to load the user code from and whether to load it at all (e.g. it
>   could require a valid digital signature). In such cases, the user code
>   might have to conform to different start-up conventions.

So unless you can somehow dump the memory at `0x20016AAD`, you won't be able to find out what the ROM does, and where within the ROM it jumps.

From a brief glance at the code, i'd assume the entry point to be a `0xBA40`, or maybe `0xBAC0` which calls `0xBA40`, because this calls `0x0960`. The first few instructions there (especially at `0x097a`)

```
ROM:00000960                 PUSH.W          {R4-R11,LR}
ROM:00000964                 SUB             SP, SP, #0x6C
ROM:00000966                 ADD             R0, SP, #0x90+var_88
ROM:00000968                 MOVS            R1, #0x34 ; '4'
ROM:0000096A                 BL              sub_1A58
ROM:0000096E                 BL              sub_8A8
ROM:00000972                 BL              sub_266
ROM:00000976                 BL              sub_1D8
ROM:0000097A                 ADR.W           R0, aStartBootloade ; "\n\n\nstart bootloader\n"
ROM:0000097E                 BL              sub_1E94
ROM:00000982                 MOVS            R1, #1
ROM:00000984                 LDR.W           R0, =0x40020000
ROM:00000988                 BL              sub_193E
```

seem to be an indication that the bootloader starts there, and `sub_1E94` is a generic string output function (it gets called lots of times, every time with a string address in `R0`).

Comment: more likely the firmware is mapped at `0x2000000`  or possibly `0x20010000`